# Python list reversion: [::-1]?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I can't find any information on `[::-1]`.  In the [wikibooks python tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Lists), there is a section about non-continous lists, but there's no information on parameters < 0. Effects are clear, but how do you explain it?

Example Usage:

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> foo[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is as follows:

```
foo[start:end:step] # begin with 'start' and proceed by step until you reach 'end'.
```

So `foo[::-1]` means `entire list with step=-1`, so actually reversing the list.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/342473) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Just one thing to add is that:

```
foo[::-1]
```

creates a copy of given array without affecting foo itself
One may assign it as follows:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
bar = foo[::-1]
# print foo --> [1,2,3]
# print bar --> [3,2,1]
```

But to update foo, using:

```
foo.reverse()
```

is preferred

Answer (score 2):

Negative step behaves the same as in [`range(start, stop, step)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range). 
The thing to remember about negative step is that `stop` is always the excluded end, whether it's higher or lower.

It frequently surprises people that `'0123456789'[5:0:-1] == '54321'`, not `'43210'`.  If you want some sub-sequence, just in opposite order, it's much cleaner to do the reversal separately.  E.g. slices off one char from left, two from right, then reverse: `'0123456789'[1:-2][::-1] == '7654321'` s. If you don't need a copy, just want to loop, it even more readable with [`reversed()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/):

```
for char in reversed('0123456789'[1:-2]):
    ...
```